# How to get the right ACCESS_TOKEN in YouTube APIv3?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, oauth, youtube-api, google-oauth

Working with YouTube Data API v3
I want to get Access token using this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps

**[[CODE]]** :
4%2F0AdQt8qiarZnP_RFvafYA-A**BLABLA***UpZ6YlB1_Byzrvqfm9iRthXll6F6TfG_f-cGw

**[[CLIENT_ID]]** :
27501137863**BLABLA***sd2918n2gqqclurlegm6j2.apps.googleusercontent.com

**[[CLIENT_SECRET]]** :
GOCSPX-T0lF1yVLJ***BLABLA**GgfL7qvcwB5p

**I send a POST request:**
screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVaUx.png

I get a 400 error, What's wrong?:

````
Status: 400

Pragma: no-cache
Date: Thu, 11 Aug 2022 18:14:44 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Referer
Server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
  "error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}```
````

Comment: When posting images of applications its really a good idea to swap the app over to English so that everyone on SO can read your app.  Also giving the name of the app would be a good idea to.   Welcome to stack

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoint is wrong to start with its https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token Thats why you are getting a 404

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: oauth2.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
client_id=your_client_id&
client_secret=your_client_secret&
redirect_uri=https%3A//oauth2.example.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

You may want to try watching this [Understanding Google OAuth 2.0 with curl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBC_tVJIx5w) or this [How to set up Oauth2 in PostMan.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjCauMywU2Q) although im not sure if what you are using is postman or not.

Comment: okay.  thank you. But now, if I send a request with a fresh token to the URL https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token for the first time, I think the problem is in the redirect url
`http://localhost
 or http://localhost:8080`


..tried both but they are added to approved (sse screenshot): https://habrastorage.org/webt/62/f5/49/62f549725af49795560312.png

Comment: thanks, question is resolved by myself